# Is pointer to std::unordered_set element's value valid after the container is modified?

Tags: c++

[std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)

> References and pointers to data stored in the container are only
> invalidated by erasing that element, even when the corresponding
> iterator is invalidated.

**Question**> I would like to confirm my understanding on the validity of pointers pointing to data stored in `std::unordered_set`. Based on my investigation, the pointer(i.e. `str_a`) is still valid even if the container(i.e. `uset`) is modified(excluding erasing) later.

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> uset{};
    
    // insert first element
    //
    auto [iter_a, inserted_a] = uset.emplace(std::make_unique<std::string>("hello_a"));
    
    // save the pointer to the first inserted element
    //
    const auto str_a = iter_a->get(); 
    if (inserted_a)
    {
        std::cout << str_a->c_str() << ": " << str_a->size() << std::endl;
    }

    // insert second element
    //
    auto [iter_b, inserted_b] = uset.emplace(std::make_unique<std::string>("hello_world_b"));
    const auto str_b = iter_b->get();
    if (inserted_b)
    {
        std::cout << str_b->c_str() << ": " << str_b->size() << std::endl;
    }
    
    // the pointer to first inserted element is still valid after the unordered_set is modified
    //
    std::cout << str_a->c_str() << ": " << str_a->size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
hello_a: 7
hello_world_b: 13
hello_a: 7
```

Comment: This is not a question. You need to rephrase it as a question and be more clear about what you're asking.

Comment: *"Based on my investigation, the pointer(i.e. `str_a`) is still valid even if the container(i.e. uset) is modified(excluding erasing) later."* -- is this surprising, given what you quoted? Actually, strike that. The pointer `str_a` is data stored in the container, not a pointer *to* data stored in the container. So the quote does not actually apply to your investigation.

Comment: @JaMiT, str_a is not the data stored in the container. Instead, I store a unique_ptr within the container.

Comment: Even if it wasn't a ```unique_ptr``` but ```unordered_set<string>```, pointers to the strings would remain valid. Entries in the set are individually allocated (like a linked list). That is a direct consequence of the guarantees the standard gives for pointer invalidation

Comment: (1) You **cannot** test if a pointer is valid. There is no valid C++ program that is able to do so. (2) You are not looking at a pointer **pointing to** data stored in `std::unordered_set` at all. You are looking at a pointer that **is** data stored in `std::unordered_set`. A pointer pointing to data stored in `std::unordered_set` would be `&*iter_a`.

Comment: @q0987 *"str_a is not the data stored in the container. Instead, I store a unique_ptr within the container."* -- yes, you store a unique_ptr within the container, and `str_a` is the pointer stored in the unique_ptr. So `str_a` is the data in the unique_ptr that is in the container. Thus `str_a` **is** data in the container -- containment is transitive. The quote applies to `&(*iter_a)`, not `(*iter_a).get()`.

Comment: I'd suggest don't use `auto` here, it seems like you're confusing what those type really is. (and the test is meaningless)

Comment: In terms of types, the quote applies to values of type `std::unique_ptr<std::string>&` or `std::unique_ptr<std::string>*` in your example, not `std::string*` (the type of `str_a`).